# Byte Regex with Separators

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have String that can be for example 3D-F2-C9-A6-B3

This is my regex and I've validated it by an online regex tester:

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[-]){0,}$
```

The problem is, that the example string `3D-F2-C9-A6-B3-4F` is not valid. I have to add a minus at the end like `3D-F2-C9-A6-B3-4F-`

How can I change the regex that the separators in the middle have to be set but no one at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to unroll it a bit:

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LyQQUb/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}` - 2 chars from the defined set
- `(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `-` - a literal hyphen
  - `[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}` -  2 chars from the defined set
- `$` - end of string (better option is `\z` to match the *very end* of the string)

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/8dbYXT):

```
var pattern = @"^[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*\z";
var input = "3D-F2-C9-A6-B3";
var matched = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern); // = > True
```

Comment: Often, people post a solution like `^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[-]?){0,}$` (note a `?` in `[-]?`). This way, matching is becoming non-linear, it also allows `-` to appear at the end of the string, and in some cases leads to poorer performance with very long strings. Repeating the pattern like yours (`[0-9A-Fa-f]`) is not a big problem here (you can even shorten it using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` and removing `A-Z`), else just build the pattern dynamically by defining a variable with the repeated block.